# Form Submit Validating Dynamic # of Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that displays a dynamic amount of rows with a dropdown. Each dropdown has an id of "ReasonCd#" and the number at the end increments from 0 -- accordingly with the row number. Each dropdown has a default selection of "Select Number" with a value of NULL.

I'd like to add in a form submit validation. How can I alert the user whether any of the dynamic amount of dropdown's have the default option selected?

> ```
> <select id='ReasonCd" . $counter . "'>
> <option disabled='disabled' selected='selected' value=''>Select Number</option>
> <option>blah</option>
> </select>
> ```

I've attempted to create my own jQuery but unfortunately I cannot get it to work.

(When my submit button is clicked)

> ```
> $("#submitButton").click(function() {
> $('[id^=ReasonCd]').filter(function(){
>     if($(this).text() == "Select Number"){
>         alert('Please Select a Number!!!');
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> });

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/u74fg/2/

I've added 3 dropdowns to represent 3 rows but please keep in mind that my row number is dynamic due to PHP pulling in from a SQL database. I'd like to have the submit button alert the user that the default text is still selected.

Comment: +1.. Useful question helped me too... Learned while solving it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the option selected:

```
    $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
        $('[id^=ReasonCd] option:selected').filter(function(){
        if($(this).text() == "Select Number"){
            alert('Please Select a Number!!!');
            e.preventDefault(); //cancel postback
            return false; //exit of .filter

        }
       });
    });
```

Or:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    $('[id^=ReasonCd] option:selected').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "Select Number"){
        alert('Please Select a Number!!!');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

[With multiple dropdowns](http://jsfiddle.net/mCUA7/3/)

[Live Demo Update](http://jsfiddle.net/mCUA7/)

Comment: Amazing! Is there a way to only display a message once and prevent submission? Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The form still submits when there's a default value is selected.

Comment: This is great! You're awesome.
It's still going through submission after the alert. I'll keep playing around and try to figure it out.

Comment: Why not you add a form in demo (like the asker did) and demonstrate it being prevented from submission..

Answer (score 0):

[**Here is complete working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mCUA7/5/)

You need to iterate through all options in every dropdown having id like `^=ReasonCd` and return false at the first invalid `(selectedopts.eq(i).text() == 'Select Number')` found..

Note : scope of return must be submit function

```
$("#submitButton").click(function()
{
    selectedopts = $('[id^=ReasonCd] option:selected');
    for(i=0;i<selectedopts.length;i++)
    {
        if(selectedopts.eq(i).text() == 'Select Number')
        {
            alert('Please Select a Number!!!');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Very interesting. I'm starting to learn a lot about jQuery syntax and I'm glad you've shown me a familiar way to create a working for loop with a max length variable. Thank you!